# Launch Configurations Created using AWS-Console VS Programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, programmatically-created, launch-configuration

I would like to find out if there is an easy way to find out whether given launch configuration is created using AWS Console or Programmatically?

Usecase:

We are planning to avoid copying/creating launch configuration using AWS-Console, so we would like to implement some alert system if there is any launch configuration created using AWS-Console.

So is there any way we can look at a flag on the launch configuration and differentiate if the launch configuration is created using AWS Console or not?

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought

Approach 1

1. Revoke permissions to launch configuration from all users with the console access.
2. Use separate user for the program, who has permission to launch configuration.

Approach 2

Write a program which is monitoring CloutTrail logs. because all the things we do whether via console or API are/can_be logged in CloudTrail

Comment: Approach 1: yes, but we have some exceptions, not a easy task.

Approach 2: for future creations - we can alert using CloudTrial logs, but how to find out existing mess with launch configurations? segregate launch configurations programatically vs aws console.

Comment: best and fastest way is to use Athena to analyse logs for `CreateLaunchConfiguration` API calls.

Comment: For existing infra, you can also dig in CloudTrail logs, whatever is there. I guess there is no other option.

Comment: Yes, looks like, did not find any elegant or easy solution as of now

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: Use only CloudFormation to create the LaunchConfigs and then check for the existence of relevant CF-tags.

Added bonus: you can create a specific role for CF to launch EC2 instances and then revoke all permissions for your users.

Comment: +1 to use CloudFromation to create new launch configs. But issue here is: how to segregate the existing ones which are already created.